# Shading a region under a PDF

Tags: r, plot

I've used the following to plot a Weibull distribution W(2,3):

```
Weibull=function(x){
(2*x/9)*exp(-(x^2)/9)
}
xx=seq(from=0,to=10,length.out=1000)
xx1=Weibull(xx)
plot(xx,xx1,type="l")
polygon(xx, xx1, col = "red", border = NA)
```

[PDF plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri54f.png)

I want to shade the region between (4,10) only. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xx2=seq(from=4,to=10,length.out=1000)
yy2=c(Weibull(xx2),0)
xx2=c(xx2,4)
plot(xx,xx1,type="l")
polygon(xx2, yy2, col = "red", border = NA)
```

[image: Weibull]